# How validation set in statistical learning works?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

In statistical learning, we split the data into three parts for training, validation, and test, separately. With training data we can get a model $T$, then we seem to optimize or change the model by validation data. How does that happen (since the model $T$ is sort of fixed)?

*Updated:* I see validation data set is for model selection, namely it doesn't change the model, but pick one from some. But what if we only have one model to train and test? e.g. if we wanna find the value of k and distance in a k-NN model, it seems that we only need to optimize the model instead of selecting one from some.

*A relevant question:* it is said that pixel *distance* (which I guess is subtracting RGB in each pixel and then add squares of them and them calculate the square root) is never used in kNN for image classification, this sounds reasonable since it seems to me not to provide a good way of measuring how much the objects in two images differ. But then what sort of *distance* do we define for kNN for image classification? I feel it's difficult for one to directly give such a definition (particularly so if one considers occlusion and disformation), so do we just use machine learning to let the computer decide what type of distance to use?

Comment: For your update: choosing between a 4-NN model and a 5-NN model is the same as choosing between a 5-NN model and a SVM. “Optimizing” within a model family and selecting between model families is the same thing

Comment: If you want to find the best value of $k$ to use, a (possibly cross-)validation step is an obvious way to do it.  Once you have your best model and run it on the training (and validation) data, you can finally test it on the test data.  But you can only take that final test once

Comment: @astel I don't quite understand this. SVM seems to be a supervised learning method that optimizes the model by adding portions of sample data one by one, how is 4-NN a SVM? Besides, by the last sentence you mean both 'optimizing' and 'electing' a model are estimating parameters of a model so there is no fundamental difference?

Comment: @Henry I see. A validation step can be viewed as a *method* to estimate/determine the value of a (hyper)parameter which can't easily be determined with only fitting the model by training data. So it's more about a solution for solving certain problems than about a division and labeling of data set.

Comment: @astel I see what you try to say is that optimizing and selecting is fundamentally the same. (kNN is unsupervised learning and SVM is supervised learning and the two are very different, much more so than 5NN and 4NN .)

Comment: kNN is very much a supervised algorithm

Comment: @CharlieChang kNN is a supervised learning method. Did you mean k-means clustering?

Comment: Yeah, kNN is supervised learning for each data point has a Y value which differentiates some data from the others. Clustering algorithm is unsupervised learning. Thanks for pointing that out. But I still have a question, for each data point, even if it doesn’t have Y value, if D is multi dimensional then we can pick a dimension and name it Y. In that case how can we say it’s still unsupervised learning? It seems the difference btwn the two becomes not strict here.

Comment: Are you trying to predict that so-called $Y$, or do you measure it? Phrased differently, are you trying to predict a pixel in a photo that you'll have whenever you take a photo, or do you want to predict if the photo is of a dog/cat/horse/Ferrari?

Comment: I see so it depends on the variable we try to predict is included in the sample data or not

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a multiple linear regression with a penalty on the magnitude of the coefficients (otherwise Lasso).

On the Training data, you will fit your regression coefficients $\underline{w}$ by minimizing the loss function $L$.

On the Validation data, you will find the optimal value of the penalty $\lambda$ (you can find here some description about the $\lambda$ and the method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) by the minimization of the loss function $L+f(\lambda)$, where $f(\lambda)=\lambda \times \left \| \underline{w} \right \|_{2}$

If you were to fit also the $\lambda$ on the training data, then you would minimize directly the loss function $L+f(\lambda)$ and as you can see it will obtain the minimum every time for $\lambda=0.$ This will make your predictions severely biased (not to mention that you will not be able to shrinkage your coefficients).

Hence, in general, you use the Validation data to conduct model selection/ hyper parameter tuning of your model.

Comment: So can I understand it this way, for parameters like $\lambda$ in the penalty and $k$ in $kNN$, if we just use training data to estimate them, we will always have them to be 0 or any constant or a number in a very limited set, so we can only try to estimate them using validation data. It's just that some parameters can be estimated by training data (i.e. by fitting), can some cannot, and so we use validation data or model selection (i.e. by selecting one with smallest error) to estimate them. Overall, fitting and selecting are just two ways to find proper values for parameters.

Comment: The example that I described is just to show that, we cannot fit in the training set our hyperparameters because we will get results that are not meaningful. Fitting is to find the proper values for the parameters of the model (that will be universal for all the choices of our hyperparameters $\lambda$ or $k$) and model selection is to find the proper values for the hyperparameters $\lambda$ and $k$.

Comment: I see what you mean.